# How do you package GCC for distribution?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I am making a modified C++ compiler and I have it built and tested locally. However, I would like to be able to package my build for Windows, Linux (Debian), and Mac OSX.

All of the instructions I can find online deal with *building gcc* but have no regard for making something distributable (or perhaps I am missing something?). I know for Windows I will need to bundle MinGW somehow, but that only further confuses me - and I have no idea how well Mac works with GCC these days..

Can anyone layout a set of discrete high-level steps I could try on each system so I can allow people to install my modified compiler easily?

Comment: You can build a docker image to share the modified compiler, here is a tutorial for building an image for GCC https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-development-with-docker-containers-in-visual-studio-code/ . You can modify from there.

Comment: This is probably highly platform dependent.

Comment: That said, if you're on Linux, and feel like working with an RPM, [here's how to create one](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your project installs well including executables, headers, runtime dependencies.  If you're using something like cmake, this is a matter of installing things to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` while possibly appending [GnuInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GNUInstallDirs.html).  If you are using `make`, then you need to ensure that `make install --prefix=...` works well.

From here, you can target each platform independently.  Treat the packaging independently from your project.  Like Chipster mentioned, making `rpm` files isn't so tough.  `deb` files for Debian-based OSs, `tar.xz` files for Arch-based OSs are similar.  The rules for creating these packages can use your `install` rules to create the package.  You mentioned mingw.  If you're targeting an `msys` distribution of mingw for Windows deployment, then the Arch-based packaging of pacman will work on msys as well.  You can slowly work on supporting one-platform at a time with almost no changes to your actual project.

Typically in the open-source world, people will release a `tar.gz` file supporting `./configure && make && make install` or similar.  Then someone associated with the platform (like a Debian-developer) will find your project, make some packaging rules for it, and release it into their distribution.  That means your project can be totally agnostic to where it's being release.  It also means you don't really need to worry about MacOS yet, you can wait until you have someone who wants it there, or some hardware to test it on.

If you really want to be in control of how things are packaged for each platform from inside of your project, and you are already using `cmake`, `cpack` is a great tool which helps out.  After writing `cpack` rules for your project, you can simply type `cpack` to generate [many types](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cpack-generators.7.html) of deployable archives.  You won't get the resulting `*.deb` file into Debian or Ubuntu official archives, but at least people can using those formats can install your package.

Also, consider releasing one package with the runtime libraries, and one with the development content (headers, compiler, static libraries).  This way, if someone uses your compiler, they can re-distribute the runtime libraries which is probably going to be a much simpler install.